# Importing a file with different layouts to a database in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, parsing

I need to import a text file, with values separated by pipes ( | ), into a database using Java and Hibernate. The text file is generated elsewhere, and has the following layout:

#### example-file.txt

```
|0150|A|B|C|
|0150|X|Y|Z|
|0190|1|2|
|0200|9|8|7|H|F|E|
```

- Each line corresponds to a record.
- The first value (i.e 0150, 0190, 0200) is the type of info it holds (to which table it should be stored).
- The rest are the values to be stored in that table.

So far, I've been able to read the lines, find to which Object the record corresponds to - using a Factory pattern - separating the values into a String[] array and calling a method createInstance(String[] fields) to create the object and store it into the database - using a Template pattern:

#### ImportServiceInterface

```
public interface ImportServiceInterface {
    public void createInstance(String[] fields);
}
```

#### AbstractImportService

```
public abstract class AbstractImportService implements ImportServiceInterface {
    public static ImportServiceInterface getImportService(String line) {
       // returns the correct subclass
    }

    public void import() {
        createInstance(splitFields());
    }

    public String[] splitFields(String line) {
        // splits the line
    }
}
```

So I have 3 separate services, each implementing their own version of createInstance(String[] fields):

#### ImportExampleTypeService

```
public ImportExampleTypeService implements AbstractImportService {
    public void createInstance(String[] fields) {
        ExampleModel myExample = new myExampleModel(); // mapped with Hibernate
        // find which object members corresponds to the fields
        // call the DAO to store the object
    }
}
```

My problem is that the user will be able to specify his own layout: to which fields the values correspond to, size and position.

I thought about creating a table to store the layouts, then matching the names of the attributes using Reflection.

But I must be missing something, perhaps there's an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @increment1 and @Templar for your answers!

The requirements have changed. The system has to be able to import both the above format (which will not be user-defined) and a user-defined, CSV-like, flat file, with a single type of record per file. It makes my life easier. I have been looking at different flat-file parsing libraries, and I'm posting it here in case anyone stumbles upon the same problem:

- [jflat](https://code.google.com/p/jflat): simple to use, extensible and customizable framework. Probably the best choice for most.
- [BeanIO](http://www.beanio.org/): a flat-file marshaller/unmarshaller that uses xml files to figure out how to parse the file. Supports many formats, more than one type of record per file etc.
- [FFP](http://jffp.sourceforge.net/): Flat File Parsing. Also supports absolute and relative definitions, using POJOs instead of xml files. I would have chosen this one, but it seems to be dead?
- [Flatworm](http://flatworm.sourceforge.net/): very similar to BeanIO. It appears it has inspired BeanIO, and there is not much activity on Flatworm either...

I have chosen BeanIO, because its flexibility suits my project better. So here's what I am going to do:

1) Keep my design, implementing my createInstance() method as needed;

2) Use a different implementation using BeanIO for the user-defined files;

3) Use a Facade to call the parser I need:

### FacadeInterface

```
public interface ImportFacadeInterface {
    public void importFile();
}
```

### ImportDefaultLayoutFacadeImpl

```
public class ImportDefaultLayoutFacadeImpl implements ImportFacadeInterface {
    public void importFile() {
        // use the ImportServiceInterface
    }
}
```

### ImportUserDefinedLayoutFacadeImpl

```
public class ImportUserDefinedLayoutFacadeImpl implements ImportFacadeInterface {
    public void importFile() {
        // use BeanIO
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) supports custom delimiters and population of java objects via reflection, so I think it would do most of your work for you in this case.

Furthermore, it supports the concept of a header row as the first line in the file which then defines which fields those columns are mapped to in the java object, or you can just customize the column mappings manually.

Comment: @ increment1 After checking it out, I don't think it's flexible enough to fit my needs. SuperCSV expects a file holding a single type of table, but my text file holds many. The only reader that would apply would be the CsvListReader (variable columns), but I would have to implement processors for every layout possibility...

Comment: @Tarek I see what you are saying..  so you either need to use reflection like you mentioned, or avoid it by mapping the variable field orders to your existing String[] instance creation methods (e.g. store the mapping of column to array entry: map column 1 to array entry 2, etc).  I am not sure which is better or easier for your situation with the information at hand, but if you go with reflection then the Apache beanutils libs will probably help you populate your objects.

Answer (score 0):

My approch to store the possible record structures would be a Map with `|0150|` as Key and `|A|B|C|` as Value. This could be an approch to parse a line.

```
String line = ...;
String structure = map.get(line.substring(1, 4));
// Now you have the line structure and can parse it into your own format.
```

Comment: I already have the line parsed, my problem lies in populating the object using a layout specified by the user (which values correspond to which object members)...